# Maven : invalid scope value

Tags: maven, scope, dependencies

Can't find the doc related:

What happens when you declare a dependency with a "custom" scope:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>whatever</scope>
    </dependency>
```

There's no check, this one doesn't fail:

```
dependency:tree

[INFO] +- group:artifact:jar:1.0:whatever
```

Insane...

Comment: Which maven version do you use? If i try it with Maven 3.0.5 i get a WARNING.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pom validation was significantly improved in Maven 3: this is a warning since [MNG-3991](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3991):

```
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.scope' for junit:junit:jar must be one of [provided, compile, runtime, test, system] but is 'xxxx'. @ line 27, column 11
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
```

As the issue notes, even in Maven 3 it's still just a warning, rather than failure:

> This is a compromise to keep backward-compat with extensions like Flex Mojos that use custom dependency scopes.

Comment: Ok but in maven 2, in which classpath goes such dependencies?

Comment: In Maven 2, unknown scopes are [treated like `compile`](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Rationale-behind-non-standard-dependency-scopes-td5766223.html#a5766246).